# Mandar ID en la URL del Google Form y almacenarla

Tags: google-forms

He creado un formulario de *Google* y quiero que cuando se rellene la hoja de cálculo almacene el dato *ID* (identificador de la persona) es decir, quiero enviar ese *ID* en la *URL*.

Este *ID* es único y lo saco de una web en la que se tienen que loguearse los usuarios. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

He encontrado un ejemplo que está muy bien, pero no consigo sacar la `FORMKEY` en los nuevos formularios.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19mZRWDE76ijno7Y3oU7QkfxMqLmPYeHFw8f4-1vV3fE/edit?hl=en_US&hl=en_US#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que lo que quieres hacer es mas sencillo lograrlo usando el URL prellenado. En [Enviar un formulario a los encuestados](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839588?hl=es) se indica como obtenerlo.

Por otro lado, también me parece que la fuente a la que has recurrido corresponde a una versión muy vieja ya que ahora el FORMKEY es llamado simplemente `id`. Si mal no recuerdo hace tiempo el id era el mismo para el formulario en modo de edición que en modo publicado, pero ahora no. Abajo pongo un ejemplos de estos URLs, pongo en formato normal los id's.

Edición

- `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/`1t-J3rvQDnsV6avLe-mn6Zf3QALmVp8iHnKz-UYH3Fow`/edit`

Publicado

- `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/`1FAIpQLScwZm_emVRyey8N9gzD_fj-OEs5hhOrRnVM7it1KUowWPk_4A`/viewform`

Si continuas con la intención de usar el id, te podría resultar conveniente obtenerlo mediante Google Apps Script con el método [getId](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getid).